# Translate options in Angular2/TinyMce Editor

Tags: angular, tinymce, editor, primeng

I want to translate these options in Angular editor:
[image]

I mean File, Edit, View etc. How can i do this? 
My html code:

```
<editor formControlName="editor"
                apiKey="h8icf2r2w0qq04ydsf26vz3cm72b5hyypg1b6szycl5exzwh"
                [init]="{branding: false}">
        </editor>
```

Comment: could you elaborate it with some more code??

Comment: okay but what more exactly do you need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are wanting to have the user interface of TinyMCE appear in a different language you need to download the appropriate language pack(s) here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/download/language-packages/

You then reference them via one of two configuration options:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#language
https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/localization/#language_url